# how to add another language in my app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In preview tab in android studio for XML files,I want to see my project in other language (in Persian), but i don't know, how to add Persian to Language (there is only English as default).
would you please help me?

Comment: Could you post your code through editing this question? Please show us what you tried to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first make values-fa directory and make strings.xml file in this directory.
Then in preview tab new language add automatically.

فایل مربوط به زبان فارسی رو ایجاد کن به صورت خودکار زبان به تب نمایش اضافه میشه.

[image]

Comment: perfect that is ok